# Log4j2 configuration in web application

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, configuration, log4j2

I have the log4j2 jar files in my class path. Below is my Log4j2.xml. I want to write the logs to my local file "G:/test/apps.log", but I'm having two issues:

1. When I run the web application, the output is printed only to the console and not to the file.
2. I have seen a few answers which suggested putting the Log4j2.xml in `WEB-INF/classes`. However, when I do a clean build, the file will get deleted, so where should I put the configuration file?

   Note : I use Tomcat : 7.0.34, Servlet 3. I have removed the reference of Log4J in Cantalina properties.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration status="warn">
     <appenders>

       <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
       </Console>

       <File name="MyFile" fileName="G:/test/apps.log">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
       </File>  

     </appenders>

     <loggers>

       <root level="trace">
         <appender-ref ref="MyFile" level="trace" additivity="true"/>
       </root>

     </loggers>
   </configuration>
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need both the log4j-api-2.0 and the log4j-core-2.0 jar files in the classpath.
If the core jar is not found, the api jar falls back to a SimpleLogger (console) implementation.

By changing the config to `<configuration status="trace">` you can see log4j2 internal logging that may help trouble-shoot configuration issues. (This also requires the log4j-core-2.0 jar though.)

The log4j2.xml file can be in the classpath, or you can specify a location with system property `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml`,

Comment: Is there a way to just specify a folder and such as `-Dconfig.location=/path/to/folder` and then have log4j2 look into this folder to search for the `log4j2.xml` file? In my application I have already a folder where I put configuration files and also the `log4j2.xml` and I don't want to use a separate option-flag to start my application.

Comment: The alternative to the `log4j.configurationFile` system property is to put the `log4j2.xml` file in the classpath. You could include that folder (containing your configuration files) in the classpath.

Comment: I know about this. I was looking rather for a way to do this programmatically.